# Birth certificate v Baptism entry

Tags: england, birth-records, baptism-records, 1820s, wiltshire

Bulford, Wiltshire, England

Year: 1823

Why is it there are Baptism entries but no Birth entries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[A Guide to Using the Records of Civil Registration](http://www.sog.org.uk/learn/help-getting-started-with-genealogy/guide-three) from the Society of Genealogists says:

> The records of civil registration in England & Wales, which commenced
>   on 1 July 1837, relate to the birth, marriage and death of an
>   individual. ...
>
> In England & Wales, up to that time, the government had relied very
>   much on the church to register its population but it realised that it
>   was not a complete record i.e. not a full listing of the population.
>   Therefore, a single tier registration system was introduced, based on
>   the administrative poor law unions, which had been set up in 1834, and
>   previously the administrative hundreds. These became the registration
>   districts. Births, not baptisms, & deaths, not burials, were recorded
>   as well as marriages. Parish and nonconformist baptism & burial
>   registers were still completed at the same time that the new civil
>   registration system began.

A birth that led to a baptism in Bulford, Wiltshire, England in 1823 is almost 15 years too early to have been registered.  Some baptism records record the birth date alongside the baptism date.  So I think your next step should be to try and locate a transcript and image of the 1823 baptism record.

If I find a baptism record on the 6th April 1823, and it does not include a birth date, then I record the birth date as being "Before 6 Apr 1823".